# ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Premature end of file while trying to fetch file from JShare

Tags: java, sharepoint

I was trying to get the files from sharepoint and I have used JShare.
I have written below piece of code.

```
Service service = new Service("https://independentsoft.sharepoint.com", "username", "password");

List<File> files = service.getFiles("/personal/Test");

for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + files.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println("Path: " + files.get(i).getServerRelativeUrl());
    System.out.println("Length: " + files.get(i).getLength());
    System.out.println("LastModifiedTime: " + files.get(i).getLastModifiedTime());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
}
```

I am getting the error in the 2nd line as

```
JShare 1.0 evaluation version, www.independentsoft.com.
Error: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, are you trying to read some XML files from SharePoint which could not be parsed of this error?

Comment: No I just want to print all file names available in the Test folder which doesn't contain any xml file.